# filter woocommerce orders by payment gateways ( only active payment gateways )

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The snippet below filters woo-commerce orders by payment methods perfectly, but we need to amend it to list in the filter list the **used before by one of the customera at the checkout one of the payment gateway in one of the orders**

```
    /**
     * Add bulk filter for orders by payment method
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    public function filter_orders_by_payment_method() {
        global $typenow;

        if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow ) {

            // get all payment methods, even inactive ones
            $gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();

            ?>
            <select name="_shop_order_payment_method" id="dropdown_shop_order_payment_method">
                <option value="">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'All Payment Methods', 'wc-filter-orders-by-payment' ); ?>
                </option>

                <?php foreach ( $gateways as $id => $gateway ) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>" <?php echo esc_attr( isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] ) ? selected( $id, $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'], false ) : '' ); ?>>
                    <?php echo esc_html( $gateway->get_method_title() ); ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php
        }
    }


    /**
     * Process bulk filter order payment method
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     *
     * @param array $vars query vars without filtering
     * @return array $vars query vars with (maybe) filtering
     */
    public function filter_orders_by_payment_method_query( $vars ) {
        global $typenow;

        if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] ) && ! empty( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] ) ) {

            $vars['meta_key']   = '_payment_method';
            $vars['meta_value'] = wc_clean( $_GET['_shop_order_payment_method'] );
        }

        return $vars;
    }


    /** Helper methods ***************************************/


    /**
     * Main WC_Filter_Orders_By_Payment Instance, ensures only one instance is/can be loaded
     *
     * @since 1.0.0
     * @see wc_filter_orders_by_payment()
     * @return WC_Filter_Orders_By_Payment
    */
    public static function instance() {

        if ( is_null( self::$instance ) ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }


}


/**
 * Returns the One True Instance of WC_Filter_Orders_By_Payment
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @return WC_Filter_Orders_By_Payment
 */
function wc_filter_orders_by_payment() {
    return WC_Filter_Orders_By_Payment::instance();
}
```

So what we really need to achieve is if there are 3 payment gateways, but all the orders in the store are been done by customers using 2 payment gateways only so we need the drop down filter to include the only 2 payment gateways used before not all the 3 .. only the 2 that been used before from the customers during checkout or another solution: to list the only active payment gateways that are in the woocommerce>settings>pavements .. because it lists even the disabled gateways that come as default with woocommerce in the dropdown so we need the dropdown list only the active payment gateways

Comment: *"to make it list the used before payment gateway in one of the orders that one of customers already used before,"* is not clear… Try to reword your question please, as we don't understand what do you want and what you need to do…

Comment: I mean if there are 3 payment gateways, but all the orders in the store are been done by customers using 2 payment gateways only so we need the drop down filter to include the only 2 payment gateways used before not all the 3 .. only the 2 that been used before from the customers during checkout

Comment: Or another solution: to list the only active payment gateways that are in the woocommerce>settings>pavements .. because it lists even the disabled gateways that come as default with woocommerce in the dropdown so we need the dropdown list only the active payment gateways

Comment: Please edit your question, thank you :)

Comment: Done the edit of words at the top and explained it in details at the end